# Is Rice's Theorem equivalent to the Halting problem?

Tags: halting-problem, rice-theorem

As I understand it [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) seems to imply the existence of the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). That is, with Rice's Theorem, we can prove that the Halting problem is undecidable. However, to me, it seems like one could write a proof using that the Halting problem is undecidable to show Rice's Theorem. I'm not exactly sure how one would go about proving such a thing (though it seems by contradiction would be the natural thing to do), but it *feels* to me that that it should be possible?

Comment: Sure. Yup, they are equivalent; you can prove either starting from the other.  In some sense all statements that true are equivalent.  Is that useful?  Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: @D.W. "... true [and provable] are equivalent." Just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can prove Rice's theorem by reduction from the Halting problem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Proof_by_reduction_from_the_halting_problem.

The reverse direction is also provable and is trivial.

In some sense all statements that true and provable are equivalent, in the sense that you can prove any by starting from any other, but that probably isn't a useful observation.